# Eclipse configuration setup for Django can't find external libraries

Tags: python, django, eclipse

I am in the process of migrating my Django project dev environment to Eclipse.

I have Python and Django working properly in Eclipse. However, when I try to add external libraries, the project doesn't find them.

Here is how I have been adding the modules required:

1. Right-clicking on project and selecting Properties
2. Selecting the External Libraries tab
3. Either adding the source folder (which is in my virtual environment) or the egg (which is also there).

However, in both cases when I do this (for the Messages module) I get this error when doing a `syncdb`:
Error: No module named messages

I have tried restarting Eclipse, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to django, so that may be not a best practice, but it works fine for me:

- Are you using PyDev? If yes, your external libraries are stored in your_workspace/your_project/.pydevproject file like this:

```xml
<path>/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_annoying-0.7.6-py2.7.egg</path>
```

- It seems to me that this paths are used in development time for code completion and checking types and so on... but they must be in your pythonpath when your run your project and Eclipce doesn't put them to PATH automatically.
- To ensure that django apps are in PATH I add something like that to my settings_local.py:

```python
# v                        PATHS SETTINGS                              v #

import os
import sys
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')

# v                      3d-party django-apps                          v #

DJANGO_APPS_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '..', '..', 'djaddons')

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(DJANGO_APPS_ROOT, 'south'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(DJANGO_APPS_ROOT, 'annoying'))

if CONF_APP_REGISTRATION_ENABLED:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(DJANGO_APPS_ROOT, 'registration'))

# v                        python libs                                 v #

PYTHON_LIBS_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '..', '..', 'pylibs')

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PYTHON_LIBS_ROOT, 'oauth2'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PYTHON_LIBS_ROOT, 'httplib2'))

# ^                    END OF PATHS SETTINGS                           ^ #
```

(it's a part of my settings.py which is specific for environment and differs on development computer and on the server)

- Or you can add sys.path.insert statements to your .wsgi file on server (if using mod_wsgi) and to your manage.py file for testing with manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

The most common thing would be that you're adding the wrong paths... compare what you have in the command line with the paths you really added inside Eclipse by running:

```
import sys 
print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path)))
```

and fix the paths inside Eclipse.